# Proper way for multiple query insert JSON into SQL through NodeJS

Tags: mysql, sql, json, sql-server, node.js

What is the proper way of inserting complex form data into SQL (mssql) database through NodeJS.
If for example we have

```
 { 
      "newsDate": "xxxx",
      "content": [
        {
          "languageCode": "eng",
          "heading": "Head",
          "body": "Body"
        },
        {
          "languageCode": "ger",
          "heading": "Head",
          "body": "Body"
        }
      ],
      "mediaCodes": [1,2,3,4]
 }
```

Do we want to send whole JSON to NodeJS, and then split data and insert to database. Or we want to split data on client side and have multiple requests.

If we are sending all data at once, do we want to split data through loops, and create queries (Will be having procedures), and then execute them all at once with BEGIN TRANSACTION and ROLLBACK if any of queries failed, or execute one by one ?

What is proper way of doing this ?

Thank you for your time